# Getting rid of print "<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>" when using `display`

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markdown, display

I'm trying to create nice slides using **jupyter notebook** and **RISE**. One of my objectives is to display a **pandas-dataframe** in a Markdown cell in order to have some styling flexibility.

I am using the following code to display my dataframe in a Markdown cell:

```
{{Markdown(display(df_x))}}
```

After running this line, I get the following result:

[image of dataframe displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBMkq.png)

I would like to get rid of the text printed below my dataframe (<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>).

I still haven't found a way to achieve this. Could someone give me a hand?

This is the library I'm working with:

```
from IPython.display import display
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with `Markdown` class so not sure why you need that but this text printed in the output cell is coming from the fact that this `Markdown` class is returning and object and since you're not assigning it to any variable the default behavior for the notebook is to run something like `str(your_object)` which correctly returns `<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>`.
So the easiest workaround would be to just assign it to some variable like this:

```py
dummy_var = Markdown(display(df_x))

# or better yet:

_ = Markdown(display(df_x))
```

Comment: It worked great! I actually modified my code this way and it worked like a charm:

`{ { dummy_var = Markdown( display( df_x ) ) } }`

Comment: Glad it works @Roberto919 - if my answer solved your problem then please upvote it and mark it as a solution, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @Karol Żak ... your answer did help me a lot and I have already upvoted it. However, my reputation is too low for the upvote to be registered :(   Sorry